# React Native routing options. Strong and weak sides for each for the moment

Tags: react-native, routes, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux, react-native-navigation

**Native-navigation**

**React-native-navigation**

**React-native-router-flux**

**React-navigation**

1. What library have more features (including tabs, custom headers, bottom navigation, drawer menu) for the moment?
2. What are using native routing and what are not? What advantages and disadvantages of this?
3. Does react native have some built in options of navigation, is it worth to use it comparing to another options (stability and number of features)?

What library considered to be a standard?

Answer (score 1):

On my side react-navigation brings up a lot of perf issues and not logged errors, we are currently moving  to react native navigation wich have a very active comununity, but it is a big step to get into, but because it is native hope it is a lot faster than the previous